# Latex3: Passing empty token list to another command and detecting it as empty token list

Tags: expl3, token-lists, empty

I am sorting some tokens in a **token list** using the nice features of latex3 (see below command `\nom`). These tokens can be sometimes empty, and when they are empty they would trigger different conditions within another command, below called  `\amc`. The problem is that when receiving the arguments in `\amc` they are not detected as empty. Thus, the condition is never triggered.

I have already tried with passing within `\clist_if_empty:NTF \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist {**HERE**} { \clist_use:Nn \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist {,} }`

1. An empty field `{}`
2. An empty constant `\c_empty_tl`, and
3. No value token `\c_novalue_tl` (current implementation below)

and

1. `\tl_if_empty:nTF`,
2. `\tl_if_blank:nTF`, and
3. `\tl_if_eq:nnTF` (current implementation below)

without success.

Here you find the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { notation/nom }
 {
  A .tl_set:N = \l_wdsgn_notation_A_tl,
  B .tl_set:N = \l_wdsgn_notation_B_tl,
  C .tl_set:N = \l_wdsgn_notation_C_tl, 
  A .initial:n = {},
  B .initial:n = {},
  C .initial:n = {}, 
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nom}{ m O{} }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \wdsgn_notation_nom:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\clist_new:N \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist

\cs_new:Nn \wdsgn_notation_nom:nn
 {
  \keys_set:nn { notation/nom } { #2 }
% Gerneration of subscript list 
\clist_put_right:NV \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist \l_wdsgn_notation_A_tl
\clist_put_right:NV \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist \l_wdsgn_notation_B_tl
\amc{#1}
{
  \clist_if_empty:NTF \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist {\c_novalue_tl} { \clist_use:Nn \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist {,} }
}
{ % here we exploit the fact that \clist_use:Nn disregards empty items
 \clist_if_empty:NTF \l_wdsgn_notation_C_tl { \c_novalue_tl  } { \l_wdsgn_notation_C_tl }
}
}

\NewDocumentCommand \amc { m m m }
{
    (#1) -- 
    \tl_if_eq:nnTF {#2} {\c_novalue_tl} {empty} {not empty} -- 
    \tl_if_eq:nnTF {#3} {\c_novalue_tl} {empty} {not empty}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\nom{K}[A=A, B=B] \\
\nom{K}[A=A] \\
\nom{K}[B=B] \\
\nom{K}[C=guid]
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

As you can see **empty** is never printed when either `#1` or `#2` are empty.

Output:

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please note that `\clist_use:Nn` doesn't disregard empty elements, `\clist_use:nn` would.

Comment: Also please note that `\clist_if_empty:NTF \l_wdsgn_notation_C_tl` is wrong, that should be `\tl_if_empty:NTF \l_wdsgn_notation_C_tl`, and is unnecessary if you then check for emptiness in the next step again.

Comment: Another thing: Do you intend to use `\amc` on a document level? If not, I'd say you should also give it an L3 name and not define it with `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: **Comment 1**: thanks to the hint. **Comment 2**: `\clist_if_empty:NTF \l_wdsgn_notation_C_tl is wrong, that should be \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_wdsgn_notation_C_tl` is actually another clist, in the real implementation i have at least 4 clists. I just wanted to simplify the problem. **Comment 3**: `\nom` is actually i use it to sort the inputed elements, `\amc` in this case is a place holder for another function that i call to generate some equations base of the inputs sorted and grouped by `nom`. This `\amc` command has at least 8 inputs.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `\tl_if_eq:nnTF {#1} { \c_novalue_tl }` you're comparing these tokens exactly, so only a `#1` that contains exactly `\c_novalue_tl` is true (so `\tmp:n { \c_novalue_tl }` with `\tmp:n` containing this check).

Your usage of `\amc` does not expand the arguments, so `#2` will be

```
\clist_if_empty:NTF \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist {\c_novalue_tl} { \clist_use:Nn \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist {,} }
```

which is never `\c_novalue_tl` if you don't expand it with the correct number of expansion steps.

The following fixes this by expanding the first argument to `\amc` fully (`\clist_use:Nn` will prevent that the value is expanded too often), and for the second uses the value of your token list directly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { notation/nom }
 {
  A .tl_set:N = \l_wdsgn_notation_A_tl,
  B .tl_set:N = \l_wdsgn_notation_B_tl,
  C .tl_set:N = \l_wdsgn_notation_C_tl,
  A .initial:n = {},
  B .initial:n = {},
  C .initial:n = {},
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nom}{ m O{} }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \wdsgn_notation_nom:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\clist_new:N \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist

\exp_args_generate:n { neV }
\cs_new:Nn \wdsgn_notation_nom:nn
  {
    \keys_set:nn { notation/nom } { #2 }
    % Gerneration of subscript list
    \clist_put_right:NV \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist \l_wdsgn_notation_A_tl
    \clist_put_right:NV \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist \l_wdsgn_notation_B_tl
    \exp_args:NneV \amc{#1}
      {
        \clist_if_empty:NF \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist { \clist_use:Nn \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist {,} }
      }
      % here we exploit the fact that \clist_use:Nn disregards empty items
      \l_wdsgn_notation_C_tl
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \amc { m m m }
  {
    (#1) --
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#2} {empty} {not empty} --
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#3} {empty} {not empty}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\nom{K}[A=A, B=B] \\
\nom{K}[A=A] \\
\nom{K}[B=B] \\
\nom{K}[C=guid]
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your initial reply, I see that i am mainly having a token expansion problem. I added you suggestions to my main code, however now I am having another issue: asume `\amc` is a command that receives 5 inputs, each of which is a **token list** generated using the method above, how do you suggest I modify lines `\exp_args_generate:n { neV }` and `\exp_args:NneV ...` to account for the extra arguments?  The method above seems to work only for argument `#2`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Easiest solution is `\exp_last_unbraced:Ne \amc { { \clist_use:Nn ... } { \exp_not:V \l_your_variable_tl } { \exp_not:o { something-expanded-once } } ... }`, in that case it doesn't matter how many argument's you're facing. But easier would be to define an L3 name for `\amc` and use something like `\generate_variant:Nn \wdsgn_amc:nnnnn { eeeV }`.

Answer (score 4):

`\c_novalue_tl` is a very specific token list that cannot be used to test for emptiness.

You should expand the arguments before passing them to `\amc` (that I made an internal command, for this purpose).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { notation/nom }
 {
  A .tl_set:N = \l_wdsgn_notation_A_tl,
  B .tl_set:N = \l_wdsgn_notation_B_tl,
  C .tl_set:N = \l_wdsgn_notation_C_tl, 
  A .initial:n = {},
  B .initial:n = {},
  C .initial:n = {}, 
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nom}{ m O{} }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \wdsgn_notation_nom:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\clist_new:N \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \wdsgn_notation_nom:nn
 {
  \keys_set:nn { notation/nom } { #2 }
  % Gerneration of subscript list 
  \clist_put_right:NV \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist \l_wdsgn_notation_A_tl
  \clist_put_right:NV \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist \l_wdsgn_notation_B_tl
  \wdsgn_notation_amc:nee {#1}
   {
    \clist_if_empty:NTF \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist
     {empty}
     { \clist_use:Nn \l__wdsgn_notation_subscript_clist {,} }
   }
   {
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_wdsgn_notation_C_tl { empty } { \l_wdsgn_notation_C_tl }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \wdsgn_notation_amc:nnn
 {
    (#1) -- (#2) -- (#3)
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \wdsgn_notation_amc:nnn { nee }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\nom{K}[A=A, B=B]

\nom{K}[A=A]

\nom{K}[B=B]

\nom{K}[C=guid]

\end{document}
```

[image]